# Update table based on row_number in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `TBL(int x, int y)`

I want to update x based on row number

Something like this

```
UPDATE TBL 
SET X = "BLA"
WHERE ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Comment: What do you mean by row_number? Probably you have something in mind which you don't tell us :-)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers, use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: CTEs are your friends in things like this. `WITH t AS (SELECT x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (...) FROM TBL) UPDATE t SET x = ...`.

Comment: Row number over what ordering exactly? Remember that a SQL table does not have an inherent ordering, i.e. a SQL table is an unordered set of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example given in question, you need to update X based on row number. So consider Y is your primary key :

```
update t1
set t1.X = 'BLA'
from TBL  t1
join (select X, 
            Y, 
           row_number() over(order by ID) rnum
      from TBL) t2
on t1.Y = t2.Y /*since Y is the primary key*/
where t2.rnum between 1 and 3
```